# Recursive sorting function for list in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nested-loops, python-2.6, nested-lists

I want to take a list like the following:

```
groups = ["foo", "bar", "foo::fone", "foo::ftwo", "foo::ftwo::ffone"]
```

And convert it into a nested list, probably in the following format, but I'm open to suggestions:

```
groups_sorted = [{
                    "name":"foo",
                    "children": [
                                  {
                                    "name": "foo::fone",
                                    "children": [ ... ]
                                  }, ...
                                ]
                 }, ...
                ]
```

So that the list is sorted using a hierarchy split on `::`. I need each of the `children` keys to be lists themselves as the original order of the list is important.

I've played around for a few hours and been able to create a recursive dictionary starting from a single top node, but I couldn't do the last bit. Find my workings below:

```
def children_of(node, candidates):
    children = []
    remainder = []
    for c in candidates:
        sub = node + "::"
        if c.startswith(sub):
            try:
                c[len(sub):].index("::") # any more separators = not a child
                remainder.append(c)
            except ValueError: # a child
                children.append(c)    
        else: #not related
            remainder.append(c)
    return children, remainder

def sortit(l):
    if l:
        el = l.pop(0)
        children, remainder = children_of(el,l)
        if children:    
            return { "name": el,
                     "children": [sortit([c]+remainder) for c in children]
                   }
        else:
            return { "name": el }
```

**Edit**: @Thijs van Dien's solution is really good but I need 2.6 compatibility which prevents me some using OrderDicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this instead?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = OrderedDict()

def insert(name):
    current_dic = dic
    current_name = ''
    for name_elem in name.split('::'):
        current_name += ('::' if current_name else '') + name_elem
        if not current_name in current_dic:
            current_dic[current_name] = OrderedDict()
        current_dic = current_dic[current_name]

for group in ["foo", "bar", "foo::fone", "foo::ftwo", "foo::ftwo::ffone"]:
    insert(group)
```

That gives you the following structure:

```
{'bar': {}, 'foo': {'foo::fone': {}, 'foo::ftwo': {'foo::ftwo::ffone': {}}}}
```

`OrderedDict` makes sure that order is preserved, so you don't need to use any `list`. Also, you don't need to use recursion, as it is not recommended in Python.

If you don't have `OrderedDict` in the standard library, because you're using Python 2.6, you can install it:

```
pip install ordereddict
```

Then change the import:

```
from ordereddict import OrderedDict
```

Here's another solution that works only if you can assume that parents already exist when you need them. Things go bad if you have duplicate groups, so you need to adjust it for that yourself.

```
children_of_name = dict([('', list())]) # Access root with empty string

def insert(name):
    parent_name = '::'.join(name.split('::')[:-1])
    dic = dict([('name', name), ('children', list())])
    children_of_name[parent_name].append(dic)
    children_of_name[name] = dic['children']

for group in ["foo", "bar", "foo::fone", "foo::ftwo", "foo::ftwo::ffone"]:
    insert(group)
```

It gives you the structure that you proposed:

```
[{'children': [{'children': [], 'name': 'foo::fone'},
               {'children': [{'children': [], 'name': 'foo::ftwo::ffone'}],
                'name': 'foo::ftwo'}],
  'name': 'foo'},
 {'children': [], 'name': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: Thanks - sorry this is a fantastic answer but I can't use OrderedDicts as we're using Python 2.6

Comment: @IanClark Please, please list such requirements in the OP... However, you can still look up an OrderedDict recipe; you don't need to take it from the standard library.

Comment: @IanClark Added instructions to get `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I don't have access to the server, so I'll need to stick to the standard 2.6 library

Comment: @IanClark Your last option is to manually paste in this recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/. I see no point in reinventing it. And squared time complexity, what are you talking about? The code above is linear with respect to the number of elements. You might only have issues with very deep nesting because it always walks down from the top (with constant time lookups, though). You could make it smarter to avoid that. Think of some kind of binary search for which parent already exists.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this - it's quite a bit Class to import for just this one operation though don't you think?

Comment: Free, tested and flexible code that does everything you need for this and perhaps other purposes. I really don't see your point. Anyway I'm done with the changing requirements. First the ancient Python version, then packages were ruled out and now this...

Comment: sorry, I wasn't trying to sound ungrateful. I simply forgot about the Python 2.6 requirement and then wanted to check if there was a more appropriate solution for 2.6 which I still think there may be. I don't think that's disrespectful to your answer. I agree the efficiency comment didn't make much sense. The only other issue I think I see with this solution is that if a parent doesn't exist it automatically gets created, but I suppose I could easily rework that. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes, always when doing `current_dic[current_name] = OrderedDict()`, it should be the case that `name == current_name`, because otherwise you're creating a parent. However, this too is a requirement that you didn't list before. The only truly different solution involves recursion, and if you care about efficiency, that's really something to avoid. In all other cases, you're to some extent reinventing `OrderedDict`, which I think is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! The second answer seems perfect for my situation and your approach is really interesting :)